# like twitter url with rewritecond?

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like a simple help. I have a URL like this: `/profile.php?id=<id>&name=<name>`.

My .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/(.*) profile.php?id=$1&name=$2
```

So I have a end URL like this: `/profile/<id>/<name>`.

I can make `/<id>`. But how can I get a URL like `/<name>`?

I can use the `RewriteCond` to make a conditional?
I still don't a lot of .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

If the names and IDs have a different pattern in their values, you could use these patterns in your rules, for example:

```
# numerical IDs
RewriteRule ^[1-9]\d*$ profile.php?id=$0

# names
RewriteRule ^[a-z]+$ profile.php?name=$0
```